# Check what Magento patches were installed

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento-community, patches

I need to install patches 5994 and 6285 on Magento installation (Community edition) but I am not sure if they are already installed or not.

Is there any way in Magento to check if a particular patch is already installed or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When patches are applied a file named `applied.patches.list` is added in the `app/etc/` directory.

Next to that the patch is nothing more than a diff file so you can see what it should change when you open it and check in the targeted file if it is indeed changed.

You can test successful installation of the patches at https://shoplift.byte.nl

Comment: Yes, this option is there but for security reason we are not keeping the applied.patches.list and deleting it after the patch installation. Is there any other way.

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: And then crosscheck to make sure all the files reported in `applied.patches.list` have actually been updated. Magento patches have been known to skip file creation when the directory the file is supposed to be located in doesn't exist. At command line in your doc root => `find . -mtime 0 > patchdata.txt` and then download and compare `patchdata.txt` with `applied.patches.list` to make sure files reported as patched in `applied.patches.list` are listed in `patchdata.txt`

Answer (score 2):

In the app/etc directory there will be file named applied.patches.list

Comment: Yes, this option is there but for security reason we are not keeping the applied.patches.list and deleting it after the patch installation. Is there any other way.

Comment: If your server is set up properly, this file is not readable via the web server. If applied.patches.list is readable, then app/etc/local.xml will be readable, set .htaccess rules, nginx rules to exclude. One way is to diff your core against a freshly downloaded Magento install archive and note all the files that are different and check against the file changes listed in the patch files, a huge manual task. Instead of deleting the file, store applied.patches.list one level above doc root so you don't lose the information.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if `app/etc/applied.patches.list` exists and look through the text file for information.

[This module](https://github.com/philwinkle/Philwinkle_AppliedPatches) does a good job of parsing this file and displaying the patches in the admin footer.

However, this file isn't always committed/included with the project.  The only sure way would be to download the patch and compare the diff inside to your current code base.