# How to verify if a Patch has been applied to Magento CE?

Tags: patches, shell

Simple question.

How to check if a patch, in my case it's SUPEE-6285, has been applied correctly by ssh.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/74271/6414

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the full list of applied patches by looking for the file `applied.patches.list` located in:

> magento_room/app/etc

You must also consider the version of Magento you are using - latest version will have patches applied that may not appear in that list.

Comment: A few notes - if you're patching on a live environment, this file will get appended to whenever you apply a patch.  If you're patching in a test environment (and I hope you are) then this file will need to be added to your source code repository if you want to use it to track your patches.  After you've added it to your repo (or right away if you're patching live sites) you can also use Phil's plugin to read the file and display the installed patches on your Magento Backend Admin panel: Philwinkle_AppliedPatches