# Apply patch SUPEE-6285

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-6285

I have applied patch **SUPEE-6285.** Previously i have applied **SUPEE-5994.**

My Magento version is **1.9.1.0.**

I get below in my Terminal window. Is the patch properly installed?

```
sh PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh
PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: 14: PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: 127: not found
PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: 14: PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: 127: not found
PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: 25: PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh: 0: not found
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
-e ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file app/Mage.php
checking file app/code/community/Phoenix/Moneybookers/controllers/MoneybookersController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/AjaxController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Category/WidgetController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/DatafeedsController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/ReviewController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/WidgetController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Block/WidgetController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Page/WidgetController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/PageController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/WysiwygController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Customer/System/Config/ValidatevatController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/JsonController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/NotificationController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/CustomerController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ProductController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ReviewController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/SalesController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ShopcartController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/TagController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/ReportController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Rss/CatalogController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Rss/OrderController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Billing/AgreementController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/View/GiftmessageController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Recurring/ProfileController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/TransactionsController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/Config/System/StorageController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TagController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Tax/RateController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TaxController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Api2/controllers/Adminhtml/Api2/AttributeController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/controllers/Adminhtml/Bundle/SelectionController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/controllers/Adminhtml/RefreshController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/controllers/Adminhtml/Centinel/IndexController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/MultishippingController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Connect/controllers/Adminhtml/Extension/LocalController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/controllers/Adminhtml/Paygate/Authorizenet/PaymentController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/Adminhtml/Paypal/ReportsController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/controllers/CatalogController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/controllers/OrderController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Block/Adminhtml/Widget/Chooser.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/controllers/Adminhtml/WidgetController.php
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/noItems.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/failure.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/rss/order/details.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/email/rss.phtml
can't find file to patch at input line 894
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml
|index 43698c2..f4fe5ab 100644
|--- app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml
|+++ app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
checking file downloader/Maged/.htaccess
checking file downloader/Maged/Controller.php
checking file downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
checking file downloader/lib/.htaccess
checking file downloader/template/connect/packages.phtml
checking file downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 33.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file downloader/template/login.phtml
checking file downloader/template/settings.phtml
checking file errors/processor.php
www-data@www2:~/magento$
```

Answer (score 2):

You removed the `default/modern` theme but the patch tries to patch `cart.phtml` in this theme too.

**Solution:** Add `app/design/frontend/default/modern` from a fresh Magento download (should be the same version as your shop). You can also use this mirror: https://github.com/firegento/magento. Then after applying the patch successfully you may remove the theme again.

Comment: what do you mean exactly with _You can also use this mirror_? What do i have to do?

Comment: In the description there are links with all the available CE versions. Click on yours, then click "Download ZIP" in the right column

Comment: What i did was from the first patch (SUPEE-5344 and SUPEE-1533) was download the wright version, upload to root and apply the patch with SSH. Could it be maybe that those first patches also not successful applied? How do i check that? Or is that not the problem?

Comment: The problem is, that the default/modern theme is missing. I don't know if you applied the previous patches. To check it, see here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/74270/check-what-magento-patches-were-installed

Comment: About previous installed patches: In `applied.patches.list` i see `-e 2015-04-29 11:44:55 UTC | SUPEE-5344 | EE_1.14.1.0 | v1 | a5c9abcb6a387aabd6b33ebcb79f6b7a97bbde77 | Thu Feb 5 19:14:49 2015 +0200 | v1.14.1.0..HEAD
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Model/Observer.php
patching file lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php` Does this mean only `SUPEE-5344` has been installed?

Answer (score 1):

do you have the previous patches installed? If not, you will need to install them before SUPEE-6285. This is likely what is causing the problem.

Alternatively, you can upgrade to 1.9.2 which includes SUPEE-5344, SUPEE-5994 and SUPEE-6285.